# jQuery Is There A Plugin to Paginate divs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, pagination, jquery-pagination

Simple question:

I have divs in the following format that exist in a loop. I need to paginate these divs. Is there anything out there that can do it? All I find are paginators for < p > tags...

```
<div id="post_#">
<div id="post_#_inside">
    <div id="like">
    </div>
    <div id="dislike">
    </div>
    <div id="postleft">
    </div>
    <div id="postright">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The # in the ID stands for the post ID in my database.

Comment: try sm slide show plugin should be configurable.. see something like http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Comment: I'm not looking for a slider, only pagination. I want to show 10 divs per "page". Also, the idea is to not have to pay for it.

Comment: No. Pagination is taking a series of similar items and separating them into different pages, displaying only a certain amount at a time so as to not confuse your viewers by showing them everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

u can use location.hash for example:

```
<a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
<a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
```

and on hash change load with ajax or just toggle visibility of pages

plugin for hash change:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/